# Add data into MySQL Database using Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

I tried to make a simple programming that allows student's data to be added, updated, deleted and viewed for my assignments. I'm already stuck at adding part. What is the correct syntax /code to use in order to insert data into the database?

I'm using Eclipse IDE software and XAMPP for this programming.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class PracticalExercise2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    Connection      con;
    Statement       stmt;
    JLabel          lblname, lblmatricnumber, lblproject,lbltajuk;
    JTextField      txtname, txtmatricnumber , txtproject;
    JButton         btntest,btnadd,btnupdate,btndelete,btnview;
    String          user,pass;
    ResultSet       rs;
    JTabbedPane     myTab;
    JPanel          pnladd,pnlupdate,pnldelete,pnlview;
    
    public PracticalExercise2() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("Registration Form using JTabbedPane");
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        //GUI SETTING FOR FORM
        lbltajuk = new JLabel("Registration Form");
        lbltajuk.setBounds(10, 20, 350, 50);
        lbltajuk.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,32));
        lbltajuk.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        add(lbltajuk);
        
        //JTabbedPane is also a panel
        myTab = new JTabbedPane();
        myTab.setBounds(20,70,350,200);
        add(myTab);
        
        pnladd      = new JPanel();
        pnlupdate   = new JPanel();
        pnldelete   = new JPanel();
        pnlview     = new JPanel();
        
        //Create and add Tab
        myTab.addTab("Add Data", pnladd);
        myTab.addTab("Update Data", pnlupdate);
        myTab.addTab("Delete Data", pnldelete);
        myTab.addTab("View Data", pnlview);
        
        btntest = new JButton("Test Connection");
        btntest.setBounds(120, 300, 150, 30);
        add(btntest);
        
        btntest.addActionListener(this);
        
        add();
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new PracticalExercise2();
    }

    void add()
    {
        pnladd.setLayout(null);
        
        lblname = new JLabel("Nama :");
        lblname.setBounds(20,20,100,30);
        pnladd.add(lblname);
        
        lblmatricnumber = new JLabel("No Matrik :");
        lblmatricnumber.setBounds(20,60,100,30);
        pnladd.add(lblmatricnumber);
        
        lblproject = new JLabel("Projek :");
        lblproject.setBounds(20,100,100,30);
        pnladd.add(lblproject);
        
        txtname = new JTextField();
        txtname.setBounds(110,20,200,30);
        pnladd.add(txtname);
        
        txtmatricnumber = new JTextField();
        txtmatricnumber.setBounds(110,60,200,30);
        pnladd.add(txtmatricnumber);
        
        txtproject = new JTextField();
        txtproject.setBounds(110,100,200,30);
        pnladd.add(txtproject);
        
        btnadd = new JButton("Add Data");
        btnadd.setBounds(120, 140, 100, 30);
        pnladd.add(btnadd);
            
        btnadd.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if (e.getSource() == btntest)
        {
            // 1. load driver
            
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException x)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "mySQL Driver cannot connect.");
            }
            
            // 2. create/open connection
            try {
                
                //testing the connection to database.
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practicaltask2", "root", "");    
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No connection error.");
                
                
            } catch (SQLException y) {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection error.");
            }
                
        }
        
        if(e.getSource() == btnadd)
        {
            String name , matric , project;
            name    = txtname.getText();
            matric  = txtmatricnumber.getText();
            project = txtproject.getText();
            
            try {
                PreparedStatement stmnt = con.prepareStatement("insert into pelajar(NULL,nama,nomatrik,projek)values(NULL,?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ((PreparedStatement) stmt).setString(2,name);
                ((PreparedStatement) stmt).setString(3,matric);
                ((PreparedStatement) stmt).setString(4,project);
                
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added Successfuly");
                
                txtname.setText("");
                txtmatricnumber.setText("");
                txtproject.setText("");
                
            
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to add data");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how about making sure you get a decent error message? Print the stacktrace, instead of just "hey, I failed"

Comment: Eliminate the null here: `pelajar(NULL,` and from the `values` too. It looks like that was intended to set some `id`? If the column has an `auto_increment`, there is no need to pass anything for this column, the DB will set it for you.

Comment: So,whats next? I still couldnr solve this

Comment: `what's next?` ... What the first comment suggested. Without other error information, we have no way to know to offer more assistance. We cannot see your system from here.